# Assign more memory to SQuirreL SQL Client

Tags: java, windows, memory, heap-memory, squirrel-sql

I am using SQuirreL 3.8.1 on Windows 10. If I open large tables I receive the following error.

> Error occurred during task execution: Java heap space

Apparently, this has something to do with the memory that is allocated to my SQuirreL installation. Therefore, I changed `-Xmx256M` in the `squirrel-sql.bat` file to `-Xmx1024M`.

```
start "SQuirreL SQL Client" /B "%LOCAL_JAVA%" -Xmx1024M -Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -cp %CP% -splash:"%SQUIRREL_SQL_HOME%/icons/splash.jpg" net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.Main %TMP_PARMS%
```

However, I still receive the same error and if I increase the allocated memory even more (e.g. `-Xmx26624M` - my computer has 32GB RAM) SquirreL will not start anymore.

> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occured. Program will exit.

How can I allocate 26624 MB memory to my SQuirreL installation. I guess it has something to do with Java 32/64 bit!?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was indeed a problem with Java. I uninstalled my existing (32bit) Java installation and downloaded and installed 'Windows Offline (64-bit)' from java.com. I was now able to allocate 26624 MB memory to SQuirreL.